# How to query data from one of two tables based on availablity

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a query which joins multiple tables. For eg.

```
Select u.username,r.role,s.salary
from user u, roles r, salary s
where u.userid = s.userid
and r.roleid = u.roleid.
```

Now I need to append the condition to get the data only if the eligibility flag is true, which can be present in two tables (default eligibility and user eligility) . If the data is in user_eligiblity i need to check from user_eligility else i need to get from default eligibility.

```
Select u.username,r.role,s.salary
from user u, roles r, salary s, default_eligility de, user_eligiblity ue
where u.userid = s.userid
and r.roleid = u.roleid
and (if ue has data check if ue.eligible=y and ue.userid = u.userid 
     else get data from de.eligibity='y' and de.roleid = u.roleid)
```

User Eligibility may or may not have have rows for the user. If it does not have have to take it from default table.

Comment: 1) tag the appropriate database, not two 2)post some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Use explicit OUTER JOINs and COALESCE() function.

Comment: @vkp - The solution to this problem can be written in ANSI SQL and work on both databases.

Comment: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` replace your `where` condition

And the final [`left join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) is the one you want to find which user have a match in `user_eligiblity` the one who doesnt will get null

[COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) will return `ue.eligible if <> null` or `de.eligible` otherwise

```
Select u.username, r.role, s.salary
from user u 
join roles r 
  on u.roleid = r.roleid
join salary s
  on u.userid = s.userid
join default_eligility de
  on u.roleid = de.roleid 
left join user_eligiblity ue
  on u.userid = ue.userid
WHERE
     COALESCE(ue.eligible, de.eligible) = 'y'
```